# Calibre. does it possible to use network samba share for library storage folder

Tags: calibre

Ubuntu xenial 16.04. Calibre 2.55. All work fine, but when i try to create an empty  library on a nas share selecting an empty Untitled Folder.

i got `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/ui.py", line 637, in library_moved
    db = LibraryDatabase(newloc, default_prefs=default_prefs)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/db/legacy.py", line 73, in __init__
    load_user_formatter_functions=not is_second_db)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/db/legacy.py", line 46, in create_backend
    load_user_formatter_functions=load_user_formatter_functions)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/db/backend.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.initialize_database()
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/db/backend.py", line 1093, in initialize_database
    cur.execute('BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION')
  File "src/cursor.c", line 236, in resetcursor
BusyError: BusyError: database is locked`

`stat ~/mountpoint/Untitled\ Folder/
  File: '/home/y/mountpoint/Untitled Folder/'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 16384  directory
Device: 31h/49d Inode: 21919       Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     y)   Gid: ( 1000/     y)`

Comment: You have no write access to the folder? Look at the options when mounting CIFS.

Comment: yes, i do 0755/drwxr-xr-x

Comment: uid 1000 user can write|read

Answer (score 1):

As it is noted [here](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#i-am-getting-errors-with-my-calibre-library-on-a-networked-drive-nas), it is not intended, even discouraged, to store your Calibre-Library on a network share and access it from different versions across different devices.

However, with some tweaking, it seems to be possible to get at least Samba shares working when mounted with CIFS. First, ensure that you have the right permissions to the share by specifying the uid option and setting it to 1000 (as was noted in the comment below your post). Then, it looks like also the nobrl option needs to be included as proposed [here](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=57606). (If someone got some insight on this and why this needs to be done, an explanation would be appreciated, I'm just a dumb little end user.)
Your final mount-command should look like this:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=your_username,password=your_password,uid=1000,nobrl //your_server_name/your_sharename /path/to/your/mountpoint
```

I can confirm that this works for me with Calibre Version 3.46.0 on Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64.